# EDI file without any third party tool

Tags: sql, ssis

i am getting EDI  file as shown below,i need to process it ,and i need to maintain primary key ,foreign key also.

```
TH*4.2*857463*01**20091015*1045*P**~~IS*7564*ACME 
PHARMACY~PHA*1234567890~PAT*MA*06*987544****SMITH*JOHN****1234 MAIN 
ST**SOMEWHERE*MA*54356**19500101*M*01*01*INDIA**BURGER~
```

Here the column delimeter is * ,also if no value is provided they also put *.

i need to store fields from

```
TH*4.2*857463*01**20091015*1045*P**~~
```

into 1 table,by seperating fields.

So it would be

```
th01       th02       th03       th04   th05            th06      th07      th08   th09         th10
TH          4.2        857163     01     *(no value)    20091015   1045       p     * (novalue)  ~~
```

IS*7564*ACME PHARMACY into another table,and so on.

i cannot use third party tool as i cannot have xml files

Any help?

ok.

here is my vb.net code

Public Enum Segments
        TH
        PHA
        PAT
        IS1
    End Enum

```
Dim arrLine As String()
Dim segmentcode As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim linenumber As Integer = 1
Dim segmenetsequence As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
Dim setid As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()






Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    arrLine = Row.LineText.Split("*"c)

    segmentcode = SegmentValue(arrLine, 0)
    Row.LineNumber = linenumber


    Row.Setid = setid

    counter = arrLine.Length
    linenumber += 1

    Select Case (segmentcode.ToUpper())

        Case Segments.TH.ToString.ToUpper()
            Row.TH01 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 1)
            Row.TH02 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 2)
            Row.TH03 = Convert.ToInt32(SegmentValue(arrLine, 3))
            Row.TH04 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 4)
            Row.TH05 = Convert.ToDateTime(SegmentValue(arrLine, 5))
            Row.TH06 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 6)
            Row.TH07 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 7)
            Row.TH08 = Convert.ToInt32(SegmentValue(arrLine, 8))
            Row.TH09 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 9)

        Case Segments.IS1.ToString.ToUpper()
            Row.IS01 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 1)
            Row.IS02 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 2)
            Row.IS03 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 3)

        Case Segments.PHA.ToString.ToUpper()

            Row.PHA01 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 1)
            Row.PHA02 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 2)
            Row.PHA03 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 3)
            Row.PHA04 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 4)
            Row.PHA05 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 5)
            Row.PHA06 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 6)
            Row.PHA07 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 7)
            Row.PHA08 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 8)
            Row.PHA09 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 9)
            Row.PHA10 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 10)
            Row.PHA11 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 11)
            Row.PHA12 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 12)


        Case Segments.PAT.ToString.ToUpper()

            Row.PAT01 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 1)
            Row.PAT02 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 2)
            Row.PAT03 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 3)
            Row.PAT04 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 4)
            Row.PAT05 = Convert.ToInt32(SegmentValue(arrLine, 5))
            Row.PAT06 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 6)
            Row.PAT07 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 7)
            Row.PAT08 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 8)
            Row.PAT09 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 9)
            Row.PAT10 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 10)
            Row.PAT11 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 11)
            Row.PAT12 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 12)
            Row.PAT13 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 13)
            Row.PAT14 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 14)
            Row.PAT15 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 15)
            Row.PAT16 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 16)
            Row.PAT17 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 17)
            Row.PAT18 = Convert.ToDateTime(SegmentValue(arrLine, 18))
            Row.PAT19 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 19)
            Row.PAT20 = Convert.ToInt32(SegmentValue(arrLine, 20))
            Row.PAT21 = Convert.ToInt32(SegmentValue(arrLine, 21))
            Row.PAT22 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 22)
            Row.PAT23 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 23)
            Row.PAT24 = SegmentValue(arrLine, 24)




    End Select



End Sub

Public Function SegmentValue(ByRef LineArray As String(), ByVal Counter As Integer) As String
    Throw New NotImplementedException

    If LineArray.Length > Counter Then
        Return LineArray(Counter).ToString().Trim()

    End If
    Return String.Empty

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: "Any help?" is the only question you asked in that entire post, and it's not a question that can be answered. Please edit your question to first improve it to an answerable question, and second to add some code formatting to it to make it more readable.

Comment: i need method to process this file without using any third party tool

Comment: So what have you tried? Parsing the file is very easy; you just grab the part between each pair of delimiters (`*`) and stop each "line" (segment) when you reach `~`. The NCPDP EDI pharmacy claim file is one of the simplest to parse, but you've shown no effort to do so here. And you need to **edit** your question to actually ask one, as I asked you to do before.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in broad terms, I would look at using a Script Component as a source. It would have an output collection per "thing" the file could contain. In your example, you'd have `Output 0` with sufficient columns to describe the `th` rows above. You'd then have an `Output 1` collection that describes the `IS` data set. You'll also need to factor in any keys, possibly surrogate keys generated within the source component to keep track of your data.

Once you've defined the all the columns in the collections, then it's a simple matter of writing the parsing logic in C#/VB.NET. Once parsed, you simply assign values into those collections.

```
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    // use this to assign a value
    Output0Buffer.MyColumn = parsedValue;
    // Use this for handling a null value
    Output0Buffer.MyColumn_IsNull = true;
```

Now you can run the package and parsed data flows down the stream.

It sounds like you have foreign keys to be satisfied and surrogate values to be generated. If that is the case, I'd write most, if not all this data into a variety of staging tables and then proceed with validation and backfilling of data through repeated queries via Execute SQL Tasks chained to the Data Flow Task.

Need more detail? Edit your question and provide some yourself. We're all happy to give advice and direction but we are not in your cube and do not understand your needs.

Comment: i am using source component as a trnasform and i am going through eachand every stage.but my script component just running indefinetly.

Comment: how can i upload file or image here

Comment: Upload to one of the free hosting provider (you don't yet have enough reputation to use the built-in uploader). Edit your original question and add the link to the image there